# Nodejs Azure Redis Cache hang forever and read ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, caching, azure, node-redis, azure-redis-cache

I create a new Azure Redis Cache, which take almost 5 minutes to finish creating. I'm using the node-redis package, here's my code

```
var client = redis.createClient(
  process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
  process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1'
);
if(process.env.REDIS_HOST) {
  client.auth(process.env.REDIS_KEY);
}
```

Yes those environment variables are properly set, it just hang on for a while and raise an error:  Redis connection to mycache.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed - read ECONNRESET.

Now, when I use the redis-cli to try to connect with `redis-cli -h myhost -p 6380 -a the-auth-key` it just hang at the command line and no connection seems to be established, but no error either. It's just doing nothing. If I change the port etc, I get connection error. So I'm currently wondering what I'm doing wrong?

I've created another redis cache on a different region an plan (I took the biggest, with 99.9 SLA etc). Still, no connection is possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New caches only have the SSL endpoint (port 6380) enabled by default.  Some clients (like redis-cli) do not support SSL.  You would need to check if node-redis supports SSL.  You will get erorrs if you try to connect to the SSL port with a client that doesn't support SSL.

If you need to use a client does not support SSL, there are two options.  One is to create an SSL tunnel between the local machine and the Redis cache, using an application like 'stunnel'.  I know stunnel works well for ad-hoc scenarios like redis-cli, but I'm not sure how it would perform under production load.

The second option is to enable the non-SSL endpoint (port 6379) in the Azure portal.  However, we don't recommend this for production caches since your access key and data will all be sent in plaintext.

Comment: That was in fact the issue, the package does not currently support SSL as I understand it. Switched to option #2 until I have a better option. Thanks